# Тут я использую коги и func.py ,у меня ошибка

Tags: python, discord, pydroid

Вот мои импорты:

```
import disnake as discord
import datetime
import os
from Rimuru import func
from func.py import *
from disnake.ext import tasks
```

Далее мой код в func.py:

```
def load_json(moderation):
    with open(moderation, encoding="utf-8") as infile:
        return json.load(infile)


def write_json(moderation, content):
    with open(filename, "w") as outfile:
        json.dump(content, outfile, ensure_ascii=True, indent=4)
```

Моя **ошибка** (что пишет):

```
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/disnake/ext/commands/common_bot_base.py", line 404, in _load_from_module_spec
    spec.loader.exec_module(lib)  # type: ignore
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/storage/emulated/0/Programming/Rimuru/cogs/moderation.py", line 5, in <module>
    from Rimuru import func
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Rimuru'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in <module>
    start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
    exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 80, in <module>
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/disnake/ext/commands/common_bot_base.py", line 475, in load_extension
    self._load_from_module_spec(spec, name)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/disnake/ext/commands/common_bot_base.py", line 407, in _load_from_module_spec
    raise errors.ExtensionFailed(key, e) from e
disnake.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.moderation' raised an error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Rimuru'
```

Comment: вы установили Rimuru?

Comment: Rimuru-это папка где хранится файл func.py